# Training loss or test loss?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

In order to manipulate metrics of my model , I would like to know, I saw loss on `federated_train_data` or loss on `federated_test_data` ?
I read this :

> Training loss looks much better than evaluation loss: when using Federated Averaging (the optimization algorithm used in the Federated Learning for Image Classification tutorial) one needs to be careful interpreting metrics as they have nuanced differences from centralized model training. Especially training loss, which is the average over many sequence steps or batches. This means after one round, each client may have fit the model to their local data very well (obtaining a high accuracy), but after averaging these updates into the global model the global model may still be far away from "good", resulting in a low test accuracy. Additionally, 10 rounds may be too few; one of the original academic papers on Federated Learning demonstrated at least 20 rounds until 99% accuracy (McMahan 2016) with IID data, and more than 100 rounds in with non-IID data.

So I would like to know which is better for evaluation metrcis using this code :

```
evaluation = tff.learning.build_federated_evaluation(model_fn)
    test_metrics = evaluation(state.model, federated_test_data)
```

Or this one :

```
evaluation = tff.learning.build_federated_evaluation(model_fn)
    metrics = evaluation(state.model, federated_train_data)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently good or bad about the options you outline. It computes the same metrics, based on different data. Which one is "better" really depends on what you need it for.

---

The cited paragraph does not refer to the metrics from evaluation as you outline below, but to the metrics computed *during the training procedure* in federated learning. It is warning you that the meaning of the training loss may be subtly different from what you may be used to from other (non-FL) machine learning settings. That is because the loss is effectively computed with respect to different models, in between individual gradient steps during local training. So, you should be careful when drawing conclusions from monitoring the training loss.